# Trigger to update parent record based on child

Tags: trigger, account

I created a custom field on Account `Create_contact__c` which should be checked if any contact is inserted related to that account. I did write the following trigger to achieve this but ended up with writing SOQL queries and DML inside loop. Can someone suggest proper way to put these outside loop.

```
trigger trg3 on Contact (after insert) {
    if(trigger.isinsert){
        list<contact> con = trigger.new;
        for(contact c : con){
            list<Account> acc = [SELECT id from Account WHERE id =: c.AccountId];
            for(Account a : acc){
                a.Create_Contact__c = true;
                update a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 trigger trg3 on Contact (after insert) {
    if(trigger.isinsert){
        list<Id> accIdList = new list<id>();
        for(contact c : trigger.new){
           accIdList.add(c.AccountId); 
        }

         list<Account> acc = [SELECT id,Create_Contact__c from Account WHERE id in: accIdList];
            for(Account a : acc){
                a.Create_Contact__c = true;
              }
         update acc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code snippet :

```
trigger trg3 on Contact (after insert) {
    if(trigger.isinsert){
  set<Id> setofIds = new set<Id>();
        list<contact> con = trigger.new;
        for(contact c : con){
   setofIds.add(c.AccountId);
  }

        list<Account> acc = new list<Account>();
        for(Account a : [SELECT id, Create_Contact__c, (select id from contacts) from Account WHERE id IN : setofIds]){
    a.Create_Contact__c = true;
   acc.add(angel);
  }            
  update acc;
    }
}
```

Plz mark as best answer and let me know if this helps.