# Trigger to update parent record based on child Record Insert,Update

Tags: apex, trigger, class, before-trigger

I have three object 1. School 2.Class 3.Student . I want to If i insert,update student data than class object has a field Student Information this is update.
For Example School has A,B two record and every School have X,Y,Z 3 classes if i update/Insert Student  x Class of A school how to do?

```
  trigger ClassValueUpdate on Student__c (before insert) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            if(Trigger.isInsert){
                for(Student__c students : Trigger.new){
                    List<Class__c> classeslist = [Select id, Student_Information__c From Class__c Where Class__c.Name = 'students.Class__c' And Class__c.School__c = 'students.School__c'];
                    for(Class__c classes : classeslist){
                        classes.student_information__c = 'Students.Name';
                    }
                    upsert classeslist;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I read [Example of like this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79970/trigger-to-update-parent-record-based-on-child) But my code not work. I am new in APEX.

Comment: Hello Avinash, Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve ? The explanation you provided is not very clear.

Comment: Hello Ruchi, If i insert a student data in X class of A School than Student name appent in class field (Student Information).

Comment: ok...lets consider a **school name :** "CMS" , Class : "6th Standard" , Student name : "Tom" .   So now how do you want the expected result to be ? and the field which needs to be updated is on which object ?

Comment: Student name also update in student information field. student information field available in class object.

Comment: It seems like what you want to achieve is that if a class has 20 students then all the students name should get updated in the "Student Information" field for that class. And the names will be comma separated. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes. You are understand my problem.

Comment: Hmm...and "Class" has a lookup relationship to "Student" object ?

Comment: "school" and "class" have lookup relationship to "student" and "school" also has a lookup relationship to "class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the trigger code for the same.

```
trigger ClassValueUpdate on Student__c(after insert, after update)
{
    Set<Id> parentIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    for(Student__c record : trigger.new)
    {
        parentIdSet.add(record.Class__c);
    }

    Map<Id,Class__c> allParentRecords = new Map<Id,Class__c>([Select Student_information__c from Class__c where id in :parentIdSet]);

   for(Student__c record : trigger.new)
   {
       if(allParentRecords.size() > 0 && allParentRecords.containsKey(record.Class__c))
       {
           if(allParentRecords.get(record.Class__c).Student_information__c == null || allParentRecords.get(record.Class__c).Student_information__c == '')
           {
               allParentRecords.get(record.Class__c).Student_information__c = record.name;
           }
           else
           {
               allParentRecords.get(record.Class__c).Student_information__c = allParentRecords.get(record.Class__c).Student_information__c + ',' + record.name;
           }
       }
   }

   update allParentRecords.values();
}
```

I had tested this code on my developer org and it is working exactly as required for me. Try once from your end and let us know.

Regards!
Ruchi